# Getting 415 status code while testing a Post API with the message "message": "Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

While testing a REST controller(developed with SpringBoot) with Postman, getting 415 status code repeatedly.

Happening only with a specific post requests. other post requests are working fine. Have mimicked the working post controllers into failing ones but of no luck.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addtheatre", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public HttpStatus addTheatre(@RequestBody Theatre theatre ) {
theatrerepository.save(theatre);
return HttpStatus.OK;

}
```

Theatre Entity is as follows:-
package com.example.Model;

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


@Entity(name="Theatre")
public class Theatre {

    Theatre()
    {}
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @Column(name="address")
    @NotNull
    private String address;
    @Column(name="city")
    @NotNull
    private String city;
    @Column(name="is_active")
    @NotNull
    private Boolean is_active;
    @Transient
    private List<TheatreHall> halls;
    @Transient
    private Map <Movie,LinkedList<Time>> map;

    public Boolean getIs_active() {
        return is_active;
    }

    public void setIs_active(Boolean is_active) {
        this.is_active = is_active;
    }

    public List<TheatreHall> getHalls() {
        return halls;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setHalls(List<TheatreHall> halls) {
        this.halls = halls;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Map<Movie, LinkedList<Time>> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<Movie, LinkedList<Time>> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Theatre{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                ", is_active=" + is_active +
                ", halls=" + halls +
                ", map=" + map +
                '}';
    }

}
```

Postman testdata is as follows:-

Endpoint:-localhost:8080/addtheatre

Request:-

```
{   
"name":"PVR Mall",
"address":"Andheri",
"city":"Mumbai",
"is_active":"true"
}
```

Response:-

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-12-26T08:21:43.269+0000",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
    "path": "/addtheatre"
}
```

Expecting OK status for this POST controller.

Comment: What is your controller annotated with? `@RestController`?

Answer (score 0):

In case if you use `@RestController` to fit `@RequestMapping` defaults make sure you set `application/json` both to `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers.

If you need to send exactly UTF-8 encoded json so you will need to set `consumes` attribute explicitly:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "...", method = ...,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
```

Also there might be an implicit Jackson issue with boolean setter. Try changing your `is_active` field (that doesn't fit the convention) to `active` and it's getter\setter as:

```
private boolean active;

@JsonProperty(value="is_active")       //if needed  
public boolean isActive() {
    return this.active;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}
```

Comment: Considered it but still the same error. Controller & Entity are as follows:-  Entity specification:- @JsonProperty(value="is_active")
    public Boolean getisactive() {
        return isactive;
    }
    public void setisactive(Boolean isactive) {
        this.isactive = isactive;
    } Controller is as follows:- @RequestMapping(value="/addtheatre", method= RequestMethod.POST ,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_PROBLEM_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public HttpStatus addTheatre(@RequestBody Theatre theatre ) {
        theatrerepository.save(theatre);
        return HttpStatus.OK;

    }

Comment: Is your controller annotated with @RestController annotation?

Comment: Also please confirm that you are sending JSON (not a plain text as stated in the title). Did you add an `Accept` header into your request?

You can also play switching the `consumes` attribute from `MediaType.APPLICATION_PROBLEM_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` to `MediaType.APPLICATION_PROBLEM_JSON_VALUE` and back.

Comment: No not working. Can it be because of cookie because I'm able to use anothe r POST API successfully and I, by mistake, deleted the cookie for the API that we are trying to resolve. In the cookie for this API, HTTP parameter is being sent to false where as in the API, that is working fine, it is true.

Answer (score 0):

it might be because of missing consumes and produces values inside the @RequestMapping of a Web Service method, 
may add those :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addtheatre", method= RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public HttpStatus addTheatre(@RequestBody Theatre theatre ) {
   theatrerepository.save(theatre);
return HttpStatus.OK;

}
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

change is_active to isActive and setter to setIsActive. I suspect Jackson is unable to find the relevant setter for is_active due to the naming convention and therefore unable to parse the object

Answer (score 0):

you may check the headerRequest!!!!!,I think that there are some mistakes in the setting in the head.Focus on the "Content-Type",you should set it ""